# How can I reorder my Google chrome extensions?

Tags: google-chrome

I am using many Chrome extensions. How can I reorder them in the toolbar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<del>Unfortunately, as of now, there seem to be [no](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=5a1bf0026bd6283a&hl=en) [way](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=6b989b0d81ecd7a8&hl=en#all) to [make](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=56377224915c3a38&hl=en#all) Chrome remember the order of extension icons. You can try disabling the extensions and enable them in the order that needs to be shown in the toolbar, however that seldom works.</del>

Chrome 5.0.322.2 dev edition allows you to reorder the Extensions by dragging.

Comment: Nice catch. I didn't even notice the change. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ton of extensions and some are in the hamburger menu drop down, you can still click and drag to re-arrange them, but only after you show all of them.

So put you mouse right after the bookmark star and it will turn into a resizing mark.

[image: Put cursor here]

Drag the extensions area bigger and then click and drag to re-order. Then you can drag the extensions area smaller again.